# csproj.user file in C# sln

Tags: c#, .net, csproj-user

my machine did an automatic reboot, due to patch applied by my network in my company, and last error i saw reported something with the csproj.user file. Now each time i try to launch my solution, it opens and then brings the dialog to send the report to MS. If i look at the error log in event viewer it shows this

EventType clr20r3, P1 devenv.exe, P2 8.0.50727.762, P3 45716759, P4 system, P5 2.0.0.0, P6 4889de7a, P7 5a2, P8 0, P9 system.io.filenotfoundexception, P10 NIL.

EventType clr20r3, P1 devenv.exe, P2 8.0.50727.762, P3 45716759, P4 system, P5 2.0.0.0, P6 4889de7a, P7 5a2, P8 0, P9 system.io.filenotfoundexception, P10 NIL.

.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3053 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (7A2E0F92) (0)

any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the csproj.user files?

Comment: ffpf: This file does not exists on my system anymore.

Comment: The next one to delete is the hidden .suo file in your solution folder.

Answer (score 16):

I believe the .user file just has your personal IDE settings so they can be restored when you re-open VS. Apparently, your .user file became corrupted. It shouldn't hurt anything to delete it other than you will lose any personal settings in the IDE and have to redo them.

Comment: I think the same, just to be reassured was looking for truth here

Answer (score 2):

Delete the .user file. It should get recreated.

Comment: John: The user file does not exists on my system and my solution opens, shows all the files as part of the project and then brings the dialog box stating if i want to report the error to Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, some file got deleted. I hope it was part of your project and not a .net framework file. Try and recreate your project and solution and copy your file back into it.

Hopefully this is not happening when you create a new solution or project. If it is you may need to reinstall Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and one of these helped me:

1. Restored system to last known good point.
2. Opened the csproj file instead of the sln file and things were all happy.